# How to map a function name and line number by a memory address in C language?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, reflection, gcc

how can you map back function name and line number with a memory address in GCC ?

i.e assuming a prototype in C language:

```
void func() {
  // Get the address of caller , maybe this could be avoided
  MemoryAddress = get_call_address();

  // Which line from source code is executing , which calls func()
  LineNumber = get_lineno_from_symbol ( &MemoryAddress );

  // Grab the name who calls func()
  FunctionName = get_func_from_symbol ( &MemoryAddress );
}
```

So is there any existing APIs provided by GCC or whatever , that can meet my requirements ?

Many thanks for any of you response ;-P

Comment: Does your software need the functionality, or is it just for debugging? If it's just for debugging, you can use map files, and / or predefined _ _ LINE _ _ and _ _ FILE _ _ macros.

Comment: Preprocessor can give you file & line no.  E.g.  fprintf(stdout, "%s %d\n", _ _ FIL E_ _, _ _ LINE _ _);    No gap between the double underscores. ;-)

Comment: nope , __LINE__ won't help at all. I need to dynamically provide information that which part of source code failed , and from a backtrace() memory address , anyway , psmears gave the best solution , thanks all the same  ;-P

Comment: Thanks, glad the input was useful. If the answer solved your problem, you might want to click the button to "accept" the answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you include the header

```
#include <execinfo.h>
```

then you can use the [`backtrace()` function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/backtrace) to determine the address of the calling line, and [`backtrace_symbols()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/backtrace_symbols) to retrieve the names of the functions. However, this will not give you the line numbers (though it may give enough information to help with debugging, if this is what you require).

If you absolutely do need line numbers, then you'll need to:

- Ensure that your program (and all its libraries) are compiled with debugging enabled (`-g` flag to gcc)
- Use the [`addr2line` program](http://linux.die.net/man/1/addr2line) to translate addresses (retrieved from `backtrace()`) into file/line number references. You can call this from your program using `system()`, for example. It will send the output to stdout, but you can use redirection or a pipe to capture the output if required.

Answer (score 0):

With gcc you can do this using [backtrace](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html) functionality.

Comment: It's actually glibc rather than gcc that provides `backtrace()` :)