# Can an application programmatically generate its own stacktrace?

Tags: c, stack-trace

I have a program written in C that runs on Linux, MacOS and Windows. Is there a way I can call a function and generate a stack trace? This would be super-useful for me. Ideally I'd like to do it on all three platforms, but Linux is the most important. (Windows is being compiled via mingw.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For example, in GCC and the GNU `libc` C library, you can use [`backtrace()`](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Backtraces.html).

As @slugonamission suggests, Windows offers [`CaptureStackBackTrace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204633%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - thanks!

Other platforms may offer similar features.

(This is obviously a platform-dependent question.)

(On a related note, there also exist [self-disassembly libraries](http://bastard.sourceforge.net/libdisasm.html).)

Comment: For Windows, this old post may help: [POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693192/win32-backtrace-from-c-code)

Comment: Here's a [similar backtrace suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4983533/487992) that includes reference to [addr2line](http://linux.die.net/man/1/addr2line) program to translate offsets to file names and line numbers.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using [this code](https://gist.github.com/1343977) to generate debug stack traces. It uses [libunwind](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/) to get the stacktrace and [libdwfl](https://fedorahosted.org/elfutils/browser/libdwfl) to read debug information.

It produces nice Java-like stack traces, with function names and source locations. eg.:

```
at c(stack_trace.c:95)
at b(stack_trace.c:100)
at a(stack_trace.c:105)
at main(stack_trace.c:110)
```

libunwind should work on Windows and Mac, but libdwfl is Linux and ELF specific.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded libunwind and it did not compile on my Mac.

Comment: @vy32 you are right. It turns out they are both Linux specific.

Comment: Can we generate backtrace using libunwind when the program crash?

Comment: @PriteshAcharya [Just print the stacktrace in SIGSEGV signal handler](https://gist.github.com/banthar/6452707). Be careful with this code though. It's riddled with undefined behavior.

Comment: yea. I don't wanna get a new SIGSEGV inside the SIGSEGV handler. :D

Comment: i couldn't install libdwfl. it doesn't come up with elfutils. I'm using debian system.

Comment: I've been searching for a relatively straightforward way to get a stack trace with files and line numbers like this for hours and this is the first and only answer I've found. Thanks!

Comment: I agree, this works quite well. However, for some functions, if I call `debugInfo(out,(void*)(ip-4))` the function name is wrong and it would be correct calling `debugInfo(out,(void*)(ip))`. I've verified the behavior and it's consistent also with `addr2line`. I suspect I'm missing some basics about program counter arithmetics, does anyone has a clue why this is happening?

Comment: @Avio UNW_REG_IP points to instruction to which function will return. We want the instruction where the function was called. Without that offset you will get wrong line numbers. `-4` is wrong as some call instructions take less than that. Try `-1` instead.

Comment: @Banthar thanks for the suggestion, but it was my fault. I forgot to remove the `-O3` during building, so from a certain "depth" on I was missing some function call (probably inlined) and from there on line numbers were wrong. I've made a few trials with `-O0` and both -4 and -1 produce the same results. I'm still missing something about program counter arithmetics, but now at least it's working :)

Answer (score 3):

Ian Lance Taylor's libbacktrace does this. It handles stack unwinding and provides support for DWARF debugging symbols.

https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace

As of October 2020, libbacktrace supports ELF, PE/COFF, Mach-O, and XCOFF executables with DWARF debugging information. In other words, it supports GNU/Linux, *BSD, macOS, Windows, and AIX. The library is written to make it straightforward to add support for other object file and debugging formats.